# Gridview update doesn't persist on postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

```
protected void GVVAC_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    int st = Convert.ToInt32(GVVAC.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values[0].ToString());
    TextBox txtage1 = (TextBox)GVVAC.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtage");
    TextBox txtvaccinename1 = (TextBox)GVVAC.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Controls[1];
    TextBox txtadmin1 = (TextBox)GVVAC.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Controls[1];
    TextBox txtdose1 = (TextBox)GVVAC.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[5].Controls[1];

    breederdailypl.Age = Convert.ToInt32(txtage1.Text.ToString());
    breederdailypl.vaccine = txtvaccinename1.Text.ToString();
    breederdailypl.admin = txtadmin1.Text.ToString();
    breederdailypl.dose = txtdose1.Text.ToString();



    breederdailypl.Snum = st;
    dt = breederdailybal.updatevaccine(breederdailypl);
    //chkHatchdetails = objhatcheryBAL.updateHatchMasterdet(objhatcheryPL);
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, this.GetType(), "UpdateDetails", "alert('Update Successful');", true);
    GVVAC.EditIndex = -1;

    grid();

}
```

When I edit the textbox and enter the new value, the new value does not appear in the textbox.

Comment: event is fired,i tried with debug point,but new value is not come to the textbox

Comment: can you provide code of `grid()` function?

Comment: i send my grid() method also..please check it

Comment: in `dtpulmotil` you get new value for text box or old?

Comment: it takes only old value only.

Comment: so what are `breederdailypl` and `breederdailybal` objects, and what do `updatevaccine` and `GetBreederVaccination`?

Comment: can you provide code of `BindBatches`?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about the code you have written. 
But what I guess is, initially when you bind your grid view, it is out side the if(!IsPostback) condition. So write the code inside !IsPostback condition as shown below :

```
If(!IsPostback)
{
 grid();
}
```

If, it is not in **!IsPostback** condition then when you update your row it will first go to your page load, bind the grid again then it will go to your **RowUpdating** event. And because of this you will always get old value.

So I suggest to put your code to bind grid view in **if(!IsPostback)** condition.

Comment: in this case call bind for grid on updating event

Comment: yes. but initially he needs to bind the grid so that he can edit records :)

Answer (score 0):

for provide new value to textbox you must bind to grid new value, so

```
breederdailybal.updatevaccine(breederdailypl);
```

must update data that be get in

```
breederdailybal.GetBreederVaccination(breederdailypl);
```

in your case data probably not updated